# Find nth instance of a string in Notepad++

Tags: regex, find, notepad++

I'm trying to use the regular expression functionality of Notepad++ to find every 99th instance of the string "ISA" in a text document. I tried to use the regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863802/in-notepad-how-do-i-find-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-string), but I keep getting the following error:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8O50.png)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: make sure your cursor is at the beginning of the file

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem; it works for me.  Can you show some sample data you are using?

Comment: Enable *`.` matches newline*. Or use `(?s)(?:.*?ISA){98}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may enable *`.` matches newline* option, or just use an inline singleline/dotall modifier `(?s)`:

```
(?s)(?:.*?ISA){98}
```

See the settings with the result of *Find All in Current Document* (with some 300 *`1      ISA`* lines):

[image]

If you want to replace the 98th occurrence of `ISA` with, say, `USA`, use `(?s)((?:.*?ISA){97}.*?)ISA` regex and use the `$1USA` as the replacement.